# Codeigniter RESTful API - HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, mysql, api, codeigniter

I'm trying to fetch data from my MySQL database so I can create an API, but I keep getting the "error" of a bad request. My Db has a table "category" containing id, name and status.

my controller (category.php - I created an "api" folder inside the "controllers"-folder, where category.php is placed)

```
<?php

 require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

 class Category extends REST_Controller{

 public function index_get()  
 {  
  //IF CATEGORY NOT EXIST
  if(!$this->get('name'))
  {
    $this->response(NULL, 400);
  }

  //CHECK TO MODEL FUNCTION
  $category = $this->category_model->get_category($this->get('name'));

  //IF CATEGORY EXIST
  if($category)
  {
    $this->response($category, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
  }
}  

 public function index_put()  
 {  
  //
 }  

 public function index_post()  
 {  
 //
 }  

 public function index_delete()  
 {  
 //
 } 

}

?>
```

and my model (category_model.php)

```
<?php

class Category_model extends CI_Model{

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();        
}

function get_category($name){
    $query = $this->db->get('category', array('name'=>$name));
    return $query->row_array();
}

}

?>
```

Now, when I enter `http://localhost/projectfolder/ci/index.php/api/category/` - the browser shows nothing, the same does the console...

What is the issue?

Comment: try this: `http://localhost/projectfolder/ci/index.php/api/category/index_get`

Comment: @user2936213 This gives me `{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}` - but do I have to type the _get?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all your code in if(!$this->get('name')) condition.

Comment: ok I put `$category = $this->category_model->get_category($this->get('name'));` inside the `if(!$this->get('name'))` condition and I get the error `Call to a member function get_category() on a non-object`... :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your category_model using
$this->load->model("category_model");

Comment: I put `$this->load->model("category_model");` inside the `public function index_get(){...}` - no effect...

Answer (score 0):

OK I kind of solved it myself but I dont know if its the right way but it works so far. What I did was simply to trash the model, and in the controller I wrote:

```
public function index_get()  
{ 
  $this->load->database();
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM category';
  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
  $data = $query->result();

  $this->response($data, 200);
}
```

Now, all data is displayed! This can probably be done better, but at least it works... :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can try print_r() function to check data is fetched from database or not.

Comment: hmm good point, where would you do the check? Since I get the 400, I guess its not fetched?